# Displaying JSON in futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having some difficulty returning the value from returned JSON from a Future in a FutureBuilder using snapshot.data, it only shows [ Instance of... ] and not a string.

As a temporary workaround I tried to assign a variable, var returnedJson; outside the scope of the Future in hopes to be able to call it elsewhere on the page, the variable value is updated inside the Future, however even this is proving to be a problem with Flutter when trying to display the contents.

This is the JSON I am working with and the returned runtime type is List

```
[{"id":"5","title":"Title goes here"}];
```

I was expecting to be able to call it by returnedJson[0].title however that throws an error with Flutter.

NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'name'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:13
Tried calling: name)

I've tried to decode which also throws a error: _TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String')

If I encode it I just get it stringified but iterating it with [0] returns the individual strings, not the actual key:pair values.

I've also cast my variable List? returnedJson but that prevents me from accessing the values.

What else am I missing?

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchData(http.Client()),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Details>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return AppBar(
              title: Text("Title: ${returnedJson[0].title"),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution which seems to be more work for simply outputting a key:pair value from JSON.

I created a class then did the following:

```
class Details {
  final String id;
  final String title;

  Details(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title});

  factory Details.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Details(
        id: json['id'] as String,
        title: json['title'] as String;
  }
}
```

```
    var title = returnedJson.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    title.map<Details>((json) => Details.fromJson(json)).toList();
    _title = title[0]['name'];
```

Which then allowed me to use _title to return the title from my JSON.